# How to simplify condition in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in `DF[X,Y,Z]`; based on 3 columns i am deriving column A. Below is the expression which derives column A.

```
A = If X<Y-Z Then Y-Z Elsif X>Y+Z Then Y+Z ELse X
```

Currently i am not aware how to implement above expression as it is in Pandas, instead i did below way and it's working. It seems the below logic is more complex and redundant. Could you please show me how to modify below logic into this `A = If X<Y-Z Then Y-Z Elsif X>Y+Z Then Y+Z Else X`

```
DF.loc[(DF['X']<abs(DF['Y']-DF['Z']))&(DF['min']<DF['max']), 'A'] = abs(DF['Y']-DF['Z'])
DF.loc[(DF['X']>abs(DF['Y']+DF['Z']))&(DF['min']<DF['max']), 'A'] = abs(DF['Y']+DF['Z'])
DF['A'] = DF['A'].fillna(DF['X'])
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please share a sample input of your dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: The code seems sounds to me, whats the problem exactly?

Comment: There is no issue in code as such, since i am a beginner to Python guessing there could be a simplest way writing this logic. Just looking for suggestion from experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). It would be the fastest in performance.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [(df.Y - df.Z) > df.X, (df.Y + df.Z) < df.X]
choices = [df.Y - df.Z, df.Y + df.Z]

df['A'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df.X)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure your logic is applied and is easy to read and manipulate is to rewrite it into a function, which you then `.apply()` to the dataframe, row per row. For example, you can do the following (with some random data):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# let's generate some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(X = np.random.randint(1, 50, 30), 
                            Y = np.random.randint(1, 50, 30),
                            Z = np.random.randint(1, 50, 30)))

def logic(row):
    """Function to encode your logic"""
    if row['X'] < row['Y'] - row['Z']:
        return row['Y']-row['Z'] 
    elif row['X'] > row['Y'] + row['Z']:
        return row['Y'] + row['Z']
    else:
        return row['X']

df['A'] = df.apply(logic, axis=1) # axis=1 ensures you are applying row-per-row
```

This way you have a distinct function where you clearly implement the logic `A = If X<Y-Z Then Y-Z Elsif X>Y+Z Then Y+Z ELse X`, and you're able to see the conditionals directly.

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd recommend applying a function - using axis=1 gives you access to each column in each row.

In your case, this should work:

```
def getA(someRow):    
    if someRow["X"] < (someRow["Y"] -someRow["Z"]):
        return someRow["Y"] - someRow["Z"]
    elif someRow["X"] > (someRow["Y"] + someRow["Z"]):
        return someRow["Y"] + someRow["Z"]
    else:
        return someRow["X"]
```

Then you apply it with:

```
DF.apply(getA, axis=1)
```